# Knex - error: password authentication failed for user "Joshua Rieth"

Tags: windows, postgresql, npm, knex.js, pg

I am working on building out my PostgreSQL database with Knex and I keep getting this error when I run `knex migrate:latest`.

```
error: password authentication failed for user "Joshua Rieth"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\Joshua Rieth\Documents\Projects\Lambda\Labs\homerun-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\Joshua Rieth\Documents\Projects\Lambda\Labs\homerun-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\Joshua Rieth\Documents\Projects\Lambda\Labs\homerun-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joshua Rieth\Documents\Projects\Lambda\Labs\homerun-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

I am assuming that is that it has to do with my username, but it should be the default `postges` user that I used when setting up PostgreSQL. I should also mention that the user and password is in a .env file.

Spec

- PostgreSql 12
- Windows 10
- NPM 6.14.6
- pg 8.3.0
- knex 0.20.15

Answer (score 2):

When you set up knex you need to supply the username / password, unless you'd like to connect as a "current OS user". There are multiple places where you could have set up the credentials, so it would be nice if you could check them all (and inform us :) ).

One way of doing this is:

```
require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 'postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname'
})
```

Alternatively, you could set up environment variables PGUSER and PGPASSWORD, Knex connection would pick those up too.

Your `connection` could also be configured with full details rather than the link:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  version: '12.0',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});
```

To exclude your usernames / passwords from the actual code I would strongly suggest you use something like `dotenv` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

(NB: below is not about your specific error, as your username is not specified correctly) Another thing that I would check on Pg side is that you have enabled password authentication in your `pg_hba.conf`. md5 method allows for the password-hash based authentication, which should be good for you. It should look like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER    CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    all         all     123.123.123.123/32    md5
```